# What options does the asana api expect in tasks.find_by_id

Tags: ruby, asana

I'm using the `asana` gem to access the asana api.

The client documentation for the class method `find_by_id` exposed on the tasks resource (i.e. `Asana::Task`) says that it will take a hash of options. As far as I can tell looking at the little code snippet, it should be the same options as are listed on  https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/input-output-options#paths

However, when I do `client.tasks.find_by_id(123456, :fields => "this.assignee.email")`, for example, I get an `ArgumentError: unknown keyword: fields`.

What am I doing wrong? How should this work?

Also: it's unclear to me from the above page when I should be using `this` in my field specifications and when it is unnecessary.

EDIT: SOLVED!

The correct syntax is `client.tasks.find_by_id(123456, :options => { :fields => "this.assignee.email" })`

Both `:fields` and `"fields"` work.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the code in the ruby client library: https://github.com/Asana/ruby-asana/blob/423f76c14792bd4712c099161a14a10ce941b2d9/lib/asana/http_client.rb#L42

Perhaps something like `client.tasks.find_by_id(123456, {"fields" => "this.assignee.email"})` might work. Could you try that?